When reading a CSV file directly using Databricks SQL how to set options like use the first line as header
I'd like to use the following syntax to read data directly from a CSV file:
SELECT * FROM csv.`/Volumes/main/pokemon/data/pokemon.csv`

And it works, but I'd also like to set the option to use the first line as the header. The Python equivalent would be:
df = spark.read.csv('/Volumes/main/pokemon/data/pokemon.csv', header='true')

I've tried Googling the problem, but I don't even know how this type of syntax is called. My Googling lead to an alternative solution to use temporary views:
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW pokemon_raw
USING csv 
OPTIONS (
  path '/Volumes/main/pokemon/data/pokemon.csv',
  header true
);

SELECT * FROM pokemon_raw

But this is significantly more verbose, and I was hoping to use a similar solution with the syntax mentioned at the beginning, but couldn't make it work.
Any ideas how to set the first line as headers using the syntax above?

You can use read_files
select * from read_files("/Volumes/main/pokemon/data/pokemon.csv")

You can specify options with this function (but the defaults seemed sensible when I tried it)
SELECT * FROM read_files(
  '/Volumes/main/pokemon/data/pokemon.csv',
  format => 'csv',
  header => true)

and it works with Unity-Catalog Volumes.
I also couldn't find out how to configure the sugar option appropriately. I'm not sure why it would exist and not be configurable. I'll stick with read_files for now.
